# How to change the now deprecated dplyr::funs() which includes an ifelse argument?

Tags: r, dplyr

Pretty basic but I don't think I really understand the change:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

Lab_import_sql <- Lab_import %>%
    select_if(~sum(!is.na(.)) > 0) %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    mutate_if(is.character, funs(ifelse(is.character(.), trimws(.),.))) %>%
    mutate_at(.vars = Lab_import %>% select_if(grepl("'",.)) %>% colnames(),
                 .funs = gsub,
                 pattern = "'",
                 replacement = "''") %>%
    mutate_if(is.character, funs(ifelse(is.character(.), paste0("'", ., "'"),.))) %>%
    mutate_if(is.Date, funs(ifelse(is.Date(.), paste0("'", ., "'"),.)))
```

Edit:

Thanks everyone for the input, here's reproducible code and my solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

import <- data.frame(Test_Name = "Fir'st Last", 
                     Test_Date = "2019-01-01", 
                     Test_Number = 10)

import_sql <-import %>%
  select_if(~!all(is.na(.))) %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
  mutate_if(is.character, trimws) %>%
  mutate_if(is.character, list(~gsub("'", "''",.))) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, list(~paste0("'", ., "'"))) %>%
  mutate_if(is.Date, list(~paste0("'", ., "'")))
```

Comment: given how many dplyr functions you use, I think at this point you can load `library(dplyr)`

Comment: Updating very old code because of the dplyr update, I'll import it for sure.

Comment: I didn't see what is deprecated in this code. Seems nice unless the amount of reference to `dplyr` which could be replaced importing the entire library.
Anyway you can replace `ifelse` by `case_when`. e.g. `df %>% mutate( new_column = case_when( n < 1 ~ "lower", n > 1 ~ "upper", n == 1 ~ "equal", "nonsense"))` it will test as many conditions as you give, the last one is a default which will be called when all previous conditions fails.  Seems like switch case in C++.

Comment: `funs()` is soft deprecated.

Comment: The documentation suggests using `list` with the formula syntax for anonymous functions. Like here `mutate_if(is.character, list(~ifelse(is.character(.), trimws(.),.))`. Can't test without sample data

Comment: not entirely clear why you're using  `ifelse(is.character(.),...)` within a function that's used inside `mutate_if(is.character,...)` ? isn't that redundant?  Reproducible example would be great, thanks ...

Comment: e.g.   couldn't  `mutate_if(is.character, funs(ifelse(is.character(.), trimws(.),.)))`  be just `mutate_if(is.character,trimws)` ... ???

Comment: `list(~ifelse` works, `mutate_if(ifelse` is redundant so two fixes. How about the `.funs = gsub`?

Comment: It should work unchanged, that's the argument `.funs` not the deprecated function `funs()` (which was used only to pass functions to `.funs`. I'm going to move this to an answer

Comment: Looks like this is throwing an error: `select_if(grepl("'",Lab_import))`. Error in as_fun_list(.predicate, enquo(.predicate), caller_env()) : argument ".predicate" is missing, with no default

Comment: If you want to pass functions with other arguments you need to either use and anonymous function, use the formula syntax, or pass them in the `...` of `select_if`. Unfortunately I don't know what you are trying to do in that call

Answer (score 53, accepted):

As of `dplyr` 0.8.0, the [documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/funs.html) states that we should use `list` instead of `funs`, giving the example:

> Before:
>
> `funs(name = f(.))`
>
> After:
>
> `list(name = ~f(.))`

So here, the call `funs(ifelse(is.character(.), trimws(.),.))` can become instead `list(~ifelse(is.character(.), trimws(.),.))`. This is using the formula notation for anonymous functions in the `tidyverse`, where a one-sided formula (expression beginning with `~`) is interpreted as `function(x)`, and wherever `x` would go in the function is represented by `.`. You can still use full functions inside `list`.

Note the difference between the `.funs` argument of `mutate_if` and the `funs()` function which wrapped other functions to pass to `.funs`; i.e. `.funs = gsub` still works. You only needed `funs()` if you needed to apply multiple functions to selected columns or to name them something by passing them as named arguments. You can do all the same things with `list()`.

You also are duplicating work by adding `ifelse` inside `mutate_if`; that line could be simplified to `mutate_if(is.character, trimws)` since if the column is character already you don't need to check it again with `ifelse`. Since you apply only one function, no need for `funs` or `list` at all.

Comment: Excellent, that really clears up what the function was doing, could you possibly see my edit as well for the last point? Thanks!

Comment: That is a totally different question, so you should probably submit it with a new one, including details like what in words you want to do. As written, that line says if the column name contains `'` then convert the column to one concatenated with `'` at the beginning and `''` at the end.

Comment: Thanks, I just need to read up on `mutate_at()` I don't think I'm understanding the function very well.

Comment: So I have a scenario where I want to multiply all intergers by the value in another column.  In the past I would have used:
`mutate_if(is.integer, funs(. * ConvertColumn))`
What would be the approach under the new method?