# Composite functions in mutate_at

Tags: r, data-manipulation, purrr, dplyr

I have a tibble:

```
df = tibble(one = list('a', 'b'), two = list(c('p1', 'p2', 'p3'), NA_character_), three = list(NA_character_, c('z1', 'z2', 'z3')))

df
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  one   two       three    
  <chr> <list>    <list>   
1 a     <chr [3]> <chr [1]>
2 b     <chr [1]> <chr [3]>
```

I would like to replace the missing values in columns `two` and `three` with the values of column `one` using `coalesce()` and then collapse each character vector (rowwise) in `two` and `three` into a single string using `toString()`. My expected output looks like this:

```
df = tibble(one = c('a', 'b'), two = list('p1, p2, p3', 'b'), three = list('a', 'z1, z2, z3'))
df
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  one   two       three    
  <chr> <list>    <list>   
1 a     <chr [1]> <chr [1]>
2 b     <chr [1]> <chr [1]>
```

This is what I had tried initially:

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(two, three), funs(coalesce(., one) %>% map(., toString)))
```

I know that `funs()` quotes its arguments but I don't understand why it doesn't work with the pipeline. The documentation also advises that `funs` is being deprecated but I'm not sure what to use in its place. I was wondering if someone could shed some light on why the above doesn't work since I'm not at all familiar with the inner workings of scoped verbs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `map2` , use `coalesce` and then `toString`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df1 <- df %>% 
        mutate_at(vars(two, three), ~map2(., one, ~toString(coalesce(.x, .y))))

df1

#  one   two       three    
#  <chr> <list>    <list>   
#1 a     <chr [1]> <chr [1]>
#2 b     <chr [1]> <chr [1]>

df1$two
#[[1]]
#[1] "p1, p2, p3"

#[[2]]
#[1] "b"

df1$three
#[[1]]
#[1] "a"

#[[2]]
#[1] "z1, z2, z3"
```

In the above example, we use lambda style expression using `~` to use it as a function and it is true `funs` has been deprecated and has been replaced with `list()` instead. The answer and comments in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54833694/how-to-change-the-now-deprecated-dplyrfuns-which-includes-an-ifelse-argument) provides more insight into this.

Comment: Thank you @Ronak. Your explanation and the link helped clear up why `funs` isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`, we can make use of `pmap`

```
library(tidyverse)
out <- df %>% 
          mutate_at(vars(two, three),
               list(~ pmap(list(., one), ~ list(...) %>% 
                        reduce(coalesce) %>%
                        toString)))

out
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  one   two       three    
#  <chr> <list>    <list>   
#1 a     <chr [1]> <chr [1]>
#2 b     <chr [1]> <chr [1]>
out$two
#[[1]]
#[1] "p1, p2, p3"

#[[2]]
#[1] "b"

out$three
#[[1]]
#[1] "a"

#[[2]]
#[1] "z1, z2, z3"
```

---

Or using `Map` from `base R`

```
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) do.call(Map, 
     c(f = function(x, y) toString(coalesce(x, y)), list(x, df$one))))
df
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  one   two       three    
#  <chr> <list>    <list>   
#1 a     <chr [1]> <chr [1]>
#2 b     <chr [1]> <chr [1]>
df$two
#[[1]]
#[1] "p1, p2, p3"

#[[2]]
#[1] "b"

df$three
#[[1]]
#[1] "a"

#[[2]]
#[1] "z1, z2, z3"
```