# how to replace the now deprecated funs within rename_at

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying (and succeeding) at renaming multiple columns in my dataframe using this code:

```
  rename_at(c("a", "b", "c"), 
            funs(paste0(., "_revenue")))
```

However, I then get this warning:

```
funs() is soft deprecated as of dplyr 0.8.0
Please use a list of either functions or lambdas: 

  # Simple named list: 
  list(mean = mean, median = median)

  # Auto named with `tibble::lst()`: 
  tibble::lst(mean, median)

  # Using lambdas
  list(~ mean(., trim = .2), ~ median(., na.rm = TRUE))
```

I tried looking at https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select_all.html but I couldn't see any examples.

Please help.

Comment: Do you have multiple functions in `funs()` (actually I guess you wouldn't for `rename_at`)? If you only have a single function you don't need to use `list()` or `lst()`, you can just have a `~` function like `rename_at(c("a", "b", "c"), ~ paste0(., "_revenue"))`.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to use `list` instead of `funs` and add lambda style.

```
# Before:
funs(name = f(.))

# After: 
list(name = ~ f(.))
```

For example:

```
> foo <- tibble(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(10, 20, 30), c = c(100, 200, 300))
> rename_at(foo, c("a", "b", "c"), list(~ paste0(., "_revenue")))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  a_revenue b_revenue c_revenue
      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1         1        10       100
2         2        20       200
3         3        30       300
```

There is a similar question here: [How to change the now deprecated dplyr::funs() which includes an ifelse argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54833694/how-to-change-the-now-deprecated-dplyrfuns-which-includes-an-ifelse-argument)