# `funs()` was deprecated in dplyr 0.8.0

Tags: r, dplyr

Could I please get some assistance on re-writing the code below?  Every time I run it, I receive the message below.

`funs()` was deprecated in dplyr 0.8.0.

CODE:

```
bind_rows(summarise_all(., funs(if(is.numeric(.)) sum(.) else ""))) %>%
        na_if(., 0) %>%
```

I tried using `summarize ()` and `list()` but no luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the now deprecated dplyr::funs() which includes an ifelse argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54833694/how-to-change-the-now-deprecated-dplyrfuns-which-includes-an-ifelse-argument)

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#what you have been doing
summarise_all(
  head(iris),
  funs(if (is.numeric(.)) {
    sum(.)
  } else {
    ""
  })
)

#what you could do instead 
summarise_all(
  head(iris),
  ~(if (is.numeric(.)) {
    sum(.)
  } else {
    ""
  })
)

# further alternative
summarise(head(iris),
          across(where(is.numeric),sum),
          across(where(\(.)!is.numeric(.)),\(.){""}))
```